# how do i add eula to program in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I have written my program for my exams project as an It-supporter, but now i want to publish it, but before i do that, i would like to add an EULA to it, i have written the eula to the program (eula.txt).

is there anyway to add the eula to to the program, so before the program it self runs, after the user have pressed the *.exe file, the eula will popup in a textbox or something with a yes & no button (if yes is pressed, then the programs runs, if the press no the program will be closed).

kind regards.

Thomas

Comment: well to be honest, im not that very strong at programming, since this is not my major, but it has to be done to pass the exams :/. so i have googled alot and searched youtube aswell. but could not find any usefull guides

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the most basic way...

```
 if( MessageBox.Show(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Application.StartupPath + "\\EULA.txt"),"Confirm Eula",MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
           {
               //user accepted Eula
           }
           else
           {
               // user disagreed
           }
```

Comment: I would argue that this is only half an answer since it requires the user to accept the eula every time they were to run the program

Comment: @Sayse In the question he wrote "after the user have pressed the *.exe file, the eula will popup in a textbox", he doesnt specify how often. Anyways, saving the state to a configfile or to the registry shouldnt be a problem. Without information where he wants to save it (if any) you cant do a good example. Btw there are apps (mostly portable) where the Eula is shown at every startup.

Comment: Then the question is unclear and should be closed as such ("additional details to highlight exactly what you need").

Comment: thanks @BudBrot this helped me out with the issue :)